# Event handling for list items in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In all examples and questions regarding rendering list items in React.js an event handler is registered on every list item like the following:

```
class MyList extends Component {
  state = {
    list: []
  };

 // handleItemClick implementation is hidden here ..

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.list.map(item => (
          <li onClick={this.handleItemClick}> {item.text} </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

I knew from my previous experience in frontend development that it not a good practice to put the event handler for every list item, instead you should put the handler on the `<ul>` element and benefit from the event bubbling to know which list item triggered the event.

My question is: Does the react community do it the wrong way?

Comment: In case you set the handler on the `ul` element. How do you know which `li` has been clicked?

Comment: maybe from a "data-" attribute that I put on every `li` element

Comment: Still, you won't be able to know the exact clicked element. In a ReactJS point of view, setting `onClick` on every item is indeed a very good practice :)

Comment: But I think this won't be efficient in terms of memory, especially when the list starts to grow

Comment: It depends on the amount of data your are rendering. That's why you need pagination somehow. Also, I suggest you to use `key` prop for each list item. With that, React knows which components have been changed, deleted or added. For more information about lists and keys please check [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) link.

Comment: Even without the event handler if the list goes big you need to do performance improvements like recycling. But I must say asking _all the react community doing it wrong_ is a brave statement. Also I don't understand how are you gonna handle single item click with event handler on `ul`.

Comment: @bennygenel trust me I didn't intend to be blunt. I am just a beginner trying to learn. Regarding your last questions, as I said I shall put the needed data from the `li` element in `data-` attributes on the element, then retrieve them in the handler registered on the `ul`. I know it's not the best thing to do.

Thanks for pointing out that it's not easy as I thought. It would be nice if you point me to any article or blogpost about handling lists with many items.

Comment: @mersocarlin Thanks for pointing out the `key` prop issue :)

Comment: @MohammadElbanna if you are a beginner start with small things. Read the performance notes on react documentation. Be familiar with react and react ways of dealing with thing then consider dealing with big performance improvements. React is pretty good with performance by itself if you follow the guidelines. Be familiar with those and then you can decide and implement any method you like. There isn't a single way of dealing with things in react like any other framework. If you want some good guides and blog post [awesome-react](https://github.com/enaqx/awesome-react) is a good place to start